# A new logical volume appearing after reducing the size of another

Tags: ubuntu

I was following these [instructions](https://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/remove-disk-from-lvm-array-on-ubuntu/) to remove one disk from a 3-disk logical volume, and at some point a new logical volume appeared:

ls /dev/mapper
control  ubuntu--vg-root  ubuntu--vg-swap_1  vgdata-lvdata  vgdata-pvmove0

The last one appeared after reducing the size of vgdata-lvdata. Why is that? I cannot see it anywhere when running lvdisplay.
Is it related to the pvmove command I ran? Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it related to the pvmove command I ran?

Yes. pvmove LVs are temporary, and managed by pvmove. LVM tools try to hide them. That device mapper reference is harder to hide, other things use dm in addition to LVM.

Moves can take a long time to complete. Check for any running pvmove process doing I/O. Run pvmove with no arguments to resume any stopped move. If pvmove finishes without error, consider the process successful. Any stray pvmove mapper devices are not a concern. They should go away at the next regularly scheduled reboot, at the latest.

After the move completes, vgreduce should exclude this PV from the VG without complaint.

Comment: Thanks! The move is completed, so there is no need to resume anything. There was an interruption and I had to restart, so this is probably an artefact of that. The data is backed up, so all that remains is how to remove it without continuing? Running pvmove just completes without printout, and the LV is still there

Comment: No need to do anything to pvmove LVs. Just pvmove, then vgreduce.  I edited my question to mention this.